# Hypothesis testing - vaccination immunogenicity side effects and antibodies levels

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I want to conduct an experiment.

I am checking a vaccine, i want to see if the side effects to the vaccine can predict the immunogenicity of the vaccine.

I take 2 groups, 1 that after the vaccination had mild side effects, the other had serious side effects.

I will estimate the immunogenicity of the vaccine by the number of antibodies in the blood of the participants after the vaccination.

I want help in thinking which test i should use.

$H_0$: There is no difference in the immunogenicity (using mean number of antibodies in each group - $\mu$)-> $\mu_0 = \mu_1$

$H_1:$ There is a difference, and the immunogenicity in the group that has worse side effects is bigger (using mean number of antibodies - the mean number of antibodies in the group that had worse side effects is bigger)-> $\mu_0 < \mu_1$

The numbers of participants in each group will be greater than 30: $n > 30$

Therefore, i though to use $Z$ (Normal distribution) Test.

The problem: I dont know the mean In the population, i must estimate that from the group.

So, can i use $Z$ Test when i dont know the mean in the population?

Otherewise -> what should i use? Or how to estimate the mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Welch's test is what you are looking for. However, regarding you questions it sounds like you are not familar with testing at all – if you would know the population mean, there would be absolutely no point in testing. I suggest that you first go through the basics before conducting the test

Comment: Ok and do you know to tell me how can i know what $n$ I should take from each group? I know that those are questions for statistician, yet i dont have one and i need to do it if i want it or not, so i would like some help even if i am not quite good at it @lmaosome

Comment: Ok i checked it, it seems that Welch’s test is just t-test for difference between means, but we have $n>30$ So i dont see why you say i was so totally wrong...

Comment: Testing works as follows: you have an unknown parameter $\theta$ (here its a mean, or more precisely, the difference of two means). You set a framework of hypothesis and then carry out a test. The test is based on a test statistic, which is derived from the data at hand. For example, for a t-test, the test statistic is $T = \frac{\hat\theta - \theta_0}{\hat\sigma(\hat\theta}$, where $\hat\theta$ denotes an estimate for the population parameter $\theta$, and $\hat\sigma(\hat\theta)$ its estimated std dev. do you see why your questions make non sense?

Comment: no, i dont see why

Comment: "The problem: I dont know the mean In the population, i must estimate that from the group."-> you must estimate it (using the sample mean). Have a look at the aforementioned test statistic. Note that the population mean does not appear in the expression, but just an estimate ($\hat\theta$). And as I said, this is like the very basic of testing theory, which you should be already aware of when applying tests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119479/discussion-between-lmaosome-and-alon).